# method sort applies to a list returned by a function doesn't match

Tags: python, sorting, methods

```
def func():
    return [4,3,2,5]
x=func()
x.sort()
print(x) # do a sorted list in place
```

I got `[2,3,4,5]`

But

```
 x=func().sort() 
    print(x)
```

why I got `None` ?

while this code is ok :

```
def word():
    return "word"
x=func().upper()
print(x)
```

I also aplly a method on this oher  function

And this print the upper `WORD`

`func().sort()` returns 'none' , then why this method can't be apply on a function's result  ?

Regards

Comment: As you mentioned `list.sort()` does in place sorting, and it returns `None`. If you want to get sorted list as response, use the [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function which returns sorted list.

Comment: Although note that `sorted` creates a copy, which is inefficient if it isn't needed. If you want to sort in place, use `sort`, but just don't assign the return of `sort` to a variable.

Comment: In another function, `str.upper()` works because it returns string with uppercased chars

Comment: the problem is not that it makes a copy or not , sorted(func()) returns the sorted list, but I can't do func().sort() this method can't be apply to a function ! thats the thing I dont understand ...in memory the list func() is creatad then I should be able to do an in place sort ... but nop it doesn't work !  thats the reason I'm looking for . While I'm writing i just understand why upper() works good: it takes a string and returns it ( like sorted would do on each iterable. But the sort in place is not ok ! Why not ? whats the problem in memory ?

Comment: You'd do `x = func(); x.sort(); print(x)` (over three lines though instead of on one line). `sort` doesn't return the list it sorts, so you just need to not assign it to a variable. In your example, the list that's returned by `func` is never assigned anywhere, so it's given to `sort`, sorted, but then it can't be accessed so it's made eligible for garbage collection and destroyed.

Comment: Thanks !!! I'm so stupid :)) That's sure it couldn't work good ! I lost in the memory the sorted list !  thanks to you all